# I used Moodle set_config function to set configuration, then checked through get_config, and got different result. Why

Tags: php, forms, post, moodle

```
$my_var = $_POST["myVar"];
```

`$my_var` contains an array named `myVarInfoArray`.  I save it to db using [`set_config`](http://www.collinsharper.com/documentation/moodle/moodlelib_8php.html#ab2922a90d567e5ee8cef832d7ea977a7).

```
if ( isset($my_var["myVarInfoArray"]) ) {
        set_config('InfoArray', json_encode($my_var["myVarInfoArray"]), $plugin);
}
```

Then  I check it with [`get_config`](http://www.collinsharper.com/documentation/moodle/moodlelib_8php.html#a77610f064f3b7d1f2cfe1169a6f92cd3):

```
echo '<br>';
print_r(  $my_var["myVarInfoArray"]  ); // PRINTS AS EXPECTED
echo '<br><br><br>';
print_r(    json_decode(  get_config('theme_testy', 'InfoArray')  )     ); //PROBLEM =(
```

The two `print_r`'s output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array([image] => http://localhost/moodle/theme/testy/pix/images/1.jpg)
    [1] => Array([image] => http://localhost/moodle/theme/testy/pix/images/2.jpg)
    [2] => Array([image] => http://localhost/moodle/theme/testy/pix/images/3.jpg)
    [3] => Array([image] => http://localhost/moodle/theme/testy/pix/images/4.jpg)
)

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [image] => http://localhost/moodle/theme/testy/pix/images/1.jpg )
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [image] => http://localhost/moodle/theme/testy/pix/images/5.jpg )
)
```

1. **So why this difference! It is very confusing because where does
   5.jpg come from in the second print?**
2. I am also getting the following error when I submit the form, and no
   debugging messages on this middle page (which appears when
   redirecting) *although the debugging is on*:

   **Error output, so disabling automatic redirect.**

So can anyone point out what might be going wrong here? Any suggestions are welcome?

Comment: What's the value of $plugin? Also for security never access $_POST directly, use optional_param() or required_param()

Comment: Also on https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=313268